# Container packing - combinations to place 2 x 1 x 1 cubes inside a 2 x 2 x 12 container

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In how many different ways can 24 identical boxes (cuboids), each measuring 1 x 1 x 2 be packed into a single (cuboid) container measuring 2 x 2 x 12? Mirroring and rotation do not count.

This is a math problem from school (I´m in grade 9). I tried to define possible sub-arrangements of, say four of the 1 x 1 x 2 cuboids. These sub-arrangements are either "closed" or have elements protruding to the next "layer". Yet somehow this doesn´t get me any further. I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are building $(2\times2\times n)$-towers with these cuboids. A *full tower of height* $n$ is legally filled up to height $n$, and has $r$ vertical cuboids sticking out one unit on top. Make sure that the only possible values for $r$ are $0$, $2$, $4$, whereby in case $r=2$ the two vertical cuboids share a side wall. Denote by $a_r(n)$ $\>(r\in\{0,2,4\})$ the number of full towers of height $n$ having $r$ vertical cuboids sticking out on top.

It is not totally clear what you mean by "rotations and mirroring do not count". In my counting we now have
$$a_0(1)=2,\quad a_2(1)=4,\quad a_4(1)=1\ .$$
The main work  is to set up a recursion scheme
$$a_0(n+1)=\ldots,\quad a_2(n+1)=\ldots,\quad a_4(n+1)=\ldots\quad.$$
Once you have that there is the "Master Theorem" that allows you to find closed expressions for the $a_r(n)$.

Comment: So for n = 2 I would get

Comment: So for n = 2 it would be a0(2) = a0(1) + 6 = 8, a2(2) = a2(1) + 8 = 12, a4(2) = a4(1) + 1 = 2 , and continuing with n = 3 a0(3) = a0(2) + 6 = 14, a2(3) = a2(2) + 8 = 20 and a4(3) = a4(2) + 1 = 3 is that right? Since I have a closed fixed volume container 2 x 2 x 12 the answer to my question is a0(12) = ... The solutions for n = 12 with r > 0 would be sticking out and cannot be considered.